# What is the point of LOTUS if I can just compute the average of $g(X)$?

Tags: probability

The law of the unconscious statistician (LOTUS), is a theorem used to calculate the expected value of a function $g(X)=Y$ of a random variable $X$ when one knows the probability distribution of $X$ but one does **not** know the distribution of $g(X)$.

If the point of LOTUS is to find the expectation $E[g(X)]$, then the theorem suggests using $X$'s probability density and $g(X)$'s values:

$$E[g(X)]=\sum_x\,g(x)f_X(x),\;\text{(discrete)}$$
or
$$E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,g(x)f_X(x)\,dx,\;\text{(continuous).}$$

However, and here is my **question**: If we know and have access to all realizations $y=g(x)$, why don't we just compute the average of $g$ then? Why would I want to involve $X$'s PDF/PMF?

Comment: Compute the pdf of $Y$ first.

Comment: How are you planning to calculate the average of $g$? If you had $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$ and $g(x)=x^2$ then $\int_0^2 \frac{x^2}{2}\, dx = \frac{2^3}{6}-0=\frac43$ might be easier than a change of variables

Comment: For example, in the discrete case, $\overline{g}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\,\frac{g(x_i)}{N}$. Or, if you had concrete bounds $[a,b]$ in the continuous case, $\overline{g}=(b-a)\times\left[\int_a^b\,g(x)\,dx\right]$.

Comment: "Know and have access to all realizations" is exceptionally limited, because it doesn't cover common important applications such as Poisson distributions or any continuous distribution.

Comment: So, if we do not have access to all realizations $y=g(x)$, we cannot compute the expectation anyhow, so what is the use of the theorem then in practice? What am I missing?

Comment: "Access to realizations" refers to *data,* whereas your question concerns *theoretical calculations,* which is an entirely different thing.  What are you really trying to ask about??

Comment: Maybe how LOTUS is actually used in practice? What are practical instances that operate under this law?

Comment: As in your first sentence, LOTUS is "used to calculate the expected value of a function $g(X) = Y$ of a random variable $X$ when one knows the probability distribution of $X$ but one does not know the distribution of $g(X)$."